# Curly braces as argument of function

Tags: c

I've noticed in some source code the line:

```
if(pthread_create((pthread_t[]){}, 0, start_thread, pthread_args)) {
...
```

It works correctly, but how to understand the first argument?
It seems, that curly braces converts to `pthread_t[]` type.

P.s. I googled, but didn't find answer, only some guesses (some form of initialization, or legacy feature of c?)

Comment: It's a [*compound literal*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks! It is that, i would like.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a [compound literal](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5), with a constraint violation since [initializer braces cannot be empty](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9):

```
(pthread_t[]){}
```

Using `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` this produces the warning:

```
compound_literal_pthread.c:6:36: warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]
     pthread_t *ptr = (pthread_t []){};
```

The result seems to be a pointer to `pthread_t`, though I don't see this behavior documented in the gcc manual. Note that empty braces are allowed as initializers in C++, where they are equivalent to `{ 0 }`. This behavior seems to be supported for C, but undocumented, by gcc. I suspect that is what is happening here, making the above expression equivalent to:

```
(pthread_t[]){ 0 }
```

On my system, `pthread_t` is a `typedef` for `unsigned long`, so this expression would create an array of `pthread_t` containing only a `0` element. This array would decay to a pointer to `pthread_t` in the function call.

Comment: And as a perverted side-effect, the thread is not joinable because the code doesn't save the `pthread_t` accessibly.  In effect, the thread is detached, without the benefit of being formally detached.  As a way of creating a thread, it leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: I *think* every type in C can be properly initialized with `{ 0 }`, but it's not clear to me why the empty braces aren't allowed: given that any individual element of the object being initialized is allowed to be implicit, why not make that true for them all at once? (and `{ 0 }` might be technically permissible for many types, but not "right" in the sense of being clean to read)

Comment: @Leushenko-- Offhand I can't think of a type that `{ 0 }` would not work for, though there may be warnings about missing braces. IAC, I think that what you say about initializers with missing elements makes sense, if I understand you correctly. I believe that some feel like this is a "bug" in the C spec that C++ gets right. Incidentally, your observation that `{ 0 }` may not be "right" for a particular type is why I double-checked that `pthread_t` is an `unsigned long`!

Answer (score 1):

It's a [compound literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) as mentioned by @some-programmer-dude.

In this specific case it is use to create an array to store the thread_id and discharge it later without the need of creating an extra variable. That is necessary because `pthread_create` does not accept NULL as argument for `thread_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an array with `pthread[]`. You can pass values in the curly braces if you define a length for the argument.

Answer (score 0):

What you're dealing with there is an array initializer, which happens to be the empty array. You'd usually find it as:

```
int my_array[] = (int[]){10, 20, 30};
```

And it would initialize `my_array` to contain three elements. Here there are no elements, hence the awkward syntax.

Comment: is an empty brace-enclosed list considered a valid syntax? AFAIR, it must contain at least one element.

Comment: Yes, it's a valid syntax. You don't need to write the curly braces in that case but you can.

Comment: @JohannesMols-- it is not valid syntax, it is a constraint violation to use empty braces with an initializer.

Comment: `int my_array[] = (int[]){10, 20, 30};` gives `error: array initialized from non-constant array expression`. Perhaps you meant `int *my_array = (int[]){10, 20, 30};`?

Comment: Note that GCC (7.1.0 tested) permits the compound literal as initializer unless you turn on `-pedantic` warnings/errors.  For example, using `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -c di59.c` generates the error (would be warning without `-Werror`):
`di59.c:1:18: error: initializer element is not constant [-Werror=pedantic]`
`int my_array[] = (int[]){10, 20, 30};` but leave the `-pedantic` out of the options and it is given a clean bill of health.  The 'cast' portion of the compound literal should be removed as a basic initializer, of course: `int my_array[] = { 10, 20, 30 };`.